# how to run a line of code after another vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, loops

its not like coding continuously in one button.. 
Let's say I want to display "I am fine" after displaying "hello world"
I think I can do this with a timer ofcourse, but I think there is another way, that's what I want to know for now.

here's my code..

```
Private Sub btnSettings_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click
    Dim str As String = rtb.Text
    Dim star() As String

    star = str.Split("="c, ":"c)

    txtIP.Text = star(3)




End Sub
```

this method gets a part of string in the rich text box. 
now, I need "parts" of the string to display to a number of textboxes. 
so, what I want to achieve is, after executing that, can I do it again and again and again? with different indexes ofcourse. 
let's say after index 3, I want index 4, index 10 and so on.. thanks!

Comment: what blocks you to write, after the `txtIP` code another line with `txtXXX.Text = star(4)` and so on?

Comment: well, technically, we can just add more codes as it is to continue the process right? but, what I need is to do that same process with 
    'txtIP.Text = star(4)'
star(5), 6 , 7 , etc. with different delimiters. 
will it be okay if I just declare another variable? like do that 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a for each loop.

```
  For Each s As String in star
    textIP.Text = s
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' this line let us wait 1000 ms
  Next
```

This way your application got stuck. One improvement is to do windows events the other improvement is to use a thread (like a BackGroundWorker/Timer). First let us see into windows event.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 as Integer
While i2 < star.Count
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) ' this line let us wait 10ms
  Application.DoEvents() ' this lines checks every 10ms, if an event occured
  If i Mod 100 = 0 Then ' every 100 running by, we change the text
      textIP.Text = star(i2)
      i2 += 1   
  End if
  i += 1
End While
```

The last way with a BackGroundWorker or a Timer offers even more flexibility and is the way to go in a big application or if you want to change the text a long time while working with the application. To explain the complete BackGroundWorker solution it would take more time, then i have now. Just look into BackGroundWorker (bgw). In the "bgw.DoWorkEvent" you have to put similar code than the second solution here. But instead of the line "textIP.Text = star(i2)" you have to report a progress ("bgw.ReportProgress(star(i2)") and fetch the text in the "bgw.ProgressChangedEvent". "e.UserState" contains your text. Do not forget to activate ProgressReport with "bgw.WorkerSupportsProgressReport".

Comment: thanks for explaining, but what I want is to repeat the same process as the one I have posted with different indexes. I mean same code, but different output of string. since you coded txtIP.Text = star(i2) ... wouldn't it overlap the first one that I have done upon splitting? I think this might have an error.